# Font MTEXTRA.TTF issue after the last Microsoft security update

Tags: fonts, excel-2010, office-2010, aspose-cells

After the last Microsoft security update, the equation editor library was deleted, including its specific font (MTEXTRA.TTF).

This causes a dysfunction in an application I'm working on.
My App uses the Aspose Library to convert an Excel file into a PDF file.

Weird enough, I'm not using any equations in my Excel file, the application keep crushing whenever I try to convert the Excel file into the pdf one and the error I got is that the MTEXTRA font is not found!

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUNqL.png)

I managed to fix (temporary) the issue by re-installing the font.
I want to know if anyone had a similar issue and can you explain why the Aspose library search for the font if I dont use any equations?

Alternatively, can anyone tells me why the application is searching for the font in this particular path? and is it possible to change it?

For info:

- OS: Windows 7 Entreprise - 64-bit
- Aspose.Cells for .Net ( version 4.8.2)
- Office 2010

Comment: We have logged your issue in Aspose.Cells Issue Tracking System. We will analyze your issue and once we will have some news for you, we will update you about it. --- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspose.Cells collects installed fonts info from the registry i.e.

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

It seems that after the user applies the latest security update of Microsoft, the font file **MTEXTRA.TTF** is moved from path.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\EQUATION
```

but in the registry, it is still there, please see the screenshot given below.

In this case, the exception is thrown in Aspose.Cells 4.8.2.

Anyway, it works fine in latest version of Aspose.Cells i.e. 18.1.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose